# File Path Variables

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can't work out (even after a fair bit of research) how I can can set a file path in VB to point towards the desktop of the current user, regardless of what their username is. Currently, my only efforts have required hardcoding that part of the path and this is really hampering the development so any help would be greatly appreciated, my current code segment is below.

```
FileCopy(photoJobs(lastJob).imagePath, "C:/Users/James/Desktop/Backup Jobs/" & lastJob & Strings.Right((photoJobs(lastJob).imagePath), 4))
```

Which just copies the file pointed to by the first part (this bit works) to the desktop held folder, backup jobs, and renames them, it's this second part that needs changing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`  then use `Path.Combine` to glue on those other bits

Comment: Would like to know what kind of research was that bit of, as googling _vb.net get desktop path_ throws a lot of results that answer your question - some of them on StackOverflow

Comment: Josh Part, I was googling the wrong thing entirely... I was searching for "Using file path variables in vb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`(`[`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)`)` to retrieve the current user's desktop folder.